# iOS - How to set nil in UITextField (It should be visible)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I know this is tricky question.
Is there any way to visible nil value in UITextField?

I tried with this code but TextField showing blank.

```
myTextField.text = nil;
```

For this task we can't use  `myTextField.text = @"nil";` (Without using @"nil" I need to complete this task)

But It should be look like.

[image]

Comment: If you want "nil" to appear in the text field then why can't you use the code you show: `myTextField.text = @"nil";`?

Comment: @rmaddy Without using @"nil" we need to do that. Is there any other way?

Comment: no that is the only way. @RanjitChandel

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want the text `nil` to appear in the text field then the only way is to assign the text `@"nil"` to the text field.

Comment: Yes I know we can do that with @"nil", But in the given task clearly mentioned that you have to complete this without using @"nil"  ;(

Comment: See my answer. What you are asking can't be done. But please explain your strange requirement. Why are you asking to do it this way? How else do you expect to set the text if you can't set it to a string?

Comment: may be the task is to notify user when textfield is nil, try to get clarification from the given task.@RanjitChandel

Comment: @rmaddy Right now this is the only requirement I have. Soon I will get more info then definitely I will put it here.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement isn't valid. The only way to get the text `nil` to appear in the text field is to assign the actual text `@"nil"` to the text field.

It makes no sense that you to see `nil` without using `@"nil"` to do so.

Perhaps setting the placeholder to `@"nil"` is a compromise.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use only `myTextField.text = @"nil";` or instead of showing nil you can show proper message inside uitextfield or bellow textfiled input is not valid. showing nil is doesn't helps to user. you can use alert to show no input.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this seems like a strange requirement, but you could create a subclass of UITextField that overrides the getter of the text property so that it returns @"nil" if text was actually nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try This `self.textFieldName.placeholder  = @"nil";`